# Wired Image loading issue in Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am using Picasso whose dependency is added in the gradle file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

**This is My class**

```
public class ImageLoader {
    private Picasso mPicasso;
    private static ImageLoader mInstance;

    public static ImageLoader getInstance(Context context) {
        if(mInstance==null)
            mInstance = new ImageLoader(context);

        return mInstance;
    }

    private ImageLoader(Context context) {
        mPicasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).build();
    }
    private Picasso getImageLoader(Context context) {
        return mPicasso;
    }
    public void loadImage(ImageView imageView,String url) {
        mPicasso.load(url).into(imageView);
    }


}
```

And I am invoking the method like this

```
ImageLoader.getInstance(context).loadImage(holder.imgeView, url);
```

#### The issue is that it is loading the image on emulator but not on the mobile device. What is problem ?

Comment: not mine ... it's working for me ...

Comment: if you don't know how to ask don't ask ... the only symptoms that you wrote is that is not loading on real device ... as most of the SO's users has no magic orbs such question has no sens ...

Comment: Maybe you have wifi turned off?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Glide](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) library. I had the same problem using Picasso.

Libraries to include

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}

Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
    .into(ivImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your wifi on mobile don't has access to fetch those images,

so most probably a access permission issue