# Android picasso not working

Tags: android, picasso

This is my code

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
                  .load("https://dev.tfic.aviation.go.th/timthumb/?src=%2Fcontents%2Ftravel%2Fkrabi%2F190556-travel-02-03-mayha.jpg&w=684&h=342")
                  .placeholder(R.mipmap.placeholder)
                  .error(R.mipmap.placeholder)                      
                  .into(img);
```

Comment: did you add the internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: check your internet permission in manifest.xml

Comment: are your connected thorough commercial WIFI ?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010015/wired-image-loading-issue-in-picasso

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In java,

```
 Picasso.with(this)
.load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
.placeholder(Your Drawable Resource) //this is optional the image to display while the url image is downloading
.error(Your Drawable Resource)         //this is also optional if some error has occurred in downloading the image this image would be displayed
.into(imageView);
```

This may helps you